# Making a custom stretchable button template from images

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles

I was trying to make a WPF button template from 4 images: "btnNormal, btnHover, btnPressed and btnDisabled".

[image: buttons]

The thing is I don't know how to make my button look like this exactly with WPF styles. So now I am trying to make it using these images. The thing is I want my button to be stretchable and to look same on any size. To do this I need to make 3 slices for each button state image: "Top, Bottom, Left, Right, Center"

[image: sliced]

I have this XAML for now :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="StylishBlueButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Can anyone help me out, how can I make this button template?**

Comment: do you have to do it with images ? 
do you have expression blend ?

Comment: Yes.. and yes I do have expression blend.

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify something inside the VisualState, e.g.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <!--Take one half second to transition to the MouseOver state.-->
                    <VisualTransition To="MouseOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
                  </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                  <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="borderColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Cyan"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="borderColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Red"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <Ellipse>
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                  <SolidColorBrush x:Name="borderColor" Color="Black"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
              </Ellipse>
              <Ellipse x:Name="ButtonShape" Margin="5" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Border Background="DodgerBlue">
     <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Stroke="White" Margin="3" />
 </Border>
```

Place a path as per your style that you needed instead of Rectangle.